# Locking or unlocking cells in columns B and C depending on value in column A

Tags: excel

I am trying to write a vba code and totally lost.

Basicially it would mean this:

```
**Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "" 
If Range("A11").Value = "NF" Then 
Range("B11 and C11").Locked = false 
ElseIf Range("A11").Value = (anything else other than NF) Then 
Range("B11 and C11").Locked = true 
End If 'Activesheet.protect "" 
End sub**
```

I put A11 but in reality this has to apply to each row from A11 to A30.

Column A is where the employee manually fills in the project number, in B and C i have a vlookup searching the project number and brings back in b the project description and in c the project task. 
But if the employee has no project number, he has to put NF, that means he can type in B and C to explain what he worked on in B and the task he did in C.

Therefore B and C are locked at all times but if he puts NF in A well b and c have to unlock so he can type in those two columns. And he has a possibility of entering 18 projects ranging from rows 11 to 30.

The code has to be able to do this from row 11 to 30.

After two days researching on the net , this is the best i came up with, all codes i found its either if you put in this do this and if you put in this do that. But in my case, if you put in this do this and if you put in anything else do this. Just can't get around it.

Please can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Paste this code in a relevant Worksheet. Ensure to **Unlock Column A** of the worksheet to allow the users to type values even after the worksheet is being protected.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim MyRange As Range
            With Me
                Set MyRange = .Range("A11:A20") ' Change the range according to your requirement
                .Unprotect ""
                If Not Intersect(Target, MyRange) Is Nothing Then
                    If Target.Value = "NF" Then
                        Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = False
                        Target.Offset(0, 2).Locked = False
                    Else
                        Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.Worksheetfunction.Vlookup(Target.value,Thisworkbook.worksheets("Project").Range("A:E"),4,0)
                        Target.Offset(0, 2).Locked = True
Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = Application.Worksheetfunction.Vlookup(Target.value,Thisworkbook.worksheets("Project").Range("A:E"),5,0)
                    End If
                End If
                .Protect ""
            End With
        End Sub
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Doing the happy dance :) THANK YOU so much, it's working

Comment: That's great to know!, Please upvote and select the answer as final :)

Comment: I do have another question though. Is it possible to say: If cell A11 = NF unlock B11 and C11 and if cell A11 = vlookup in sheet "PROJECT" from A1 to A5000, lock cells B11 and C11

Comment: Yes it is. But need information about the colums what you have in sheet PROJECT. Basically what you want to see in Column B and Column C.

Comment: In the Sheet "Project", I have in column A the project number in column B the project date, in column C company name, in column D the project description, in column E the task requested for the project. So i want to see in colum B  the project description and in C the task requested

Comment: It stops and highlights yellow when it gets to this part:  Target.Offset(0, 2).Locked = True It manages to put the information in column B but not in column C

Comment: Based on your comment, i guess you are in debug mode in VBA. It works perfectly for me. Try the following. Save the macro file, close the excel completely, Reopen the file and try again.